# Trouble accessing a hidden_field_tag value passed to controller in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a Rails app that has two main views: an overview and a sequenced view. The user can enter data in either view. I use the same form helper for both views, but I want the redirect_to from the create action to respect the user's context. So I pass a hidden_field_tag called 'track'.

I can't seem to access the value of 'track' inside my controller.

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for([@mission, @mission.stickies.build]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 60 %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :kind, :value => kind %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :track, :value => track %>
    <class="actions"> 
        <br><%= f.submit "Add to " + kind.pluralize.capitalize %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's where I call it in one of the views:

```
<%= render :partial => "stickies/form" , :locals => { :kind => "driver", :track => 'main' } %>
```

Here's the parameters dump (from a different call):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"N3IXwNQosOfxw1ZcpfFPOLPKzHbvNyaBhAiP3ftT9GY=",
 "sticky"=>{"name"=>"Tesssksjd argghh.",
 "kind"=>"success"},
 "track"=>"{:value=>\"sequence\"}",
 "commit"=>"Add to Successes",
 "mission_id"=>"32"}
```

And here's the relevant code in my create controller:

```
if params[:track][:value] == "main" then
    redirect_to mission_path(@mission) + '#' + @sticky.kind.pluralize
    elsif params[:track][:value] == "sequence" then
    redirect_to mission_stickies_path(@mission, :kind => @sticky.kind)
end
```

I can't seem to find the syntax, or comparator, or whatever I need to access the value represented by "track"=>"{:value=>\"sequence\"}".

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Rails and Ruby, this is my first app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write it with the `:value => track`, rather do:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag :track, track %>
```

and access it with `params[:track]`

Comment: Thank you Zippie -- I tried what you suggested, which makes sense. But I get the same value for the params dump:
 "track"=>"{:value=>\"sequence\"}",
So what's the syntax in the controller to access the value of 'track'?

Comment: the params dump is exactly the same as it was before?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I restarted the web server and ran through the app to be sure.

Comment: Zippie -- it's all working right now. I don't know why the params showed up the same. Your answer works perfectly now. THANK YOU.

Comment: no problem! :) Glad i could help you. Since your new here, just a reminder, accept (and upvote) the answer that helped you.
http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask